# Find a counter example for subgroup and normal subgroup relation

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G_1, G_2, G_3$ be groups with such condition that $G_1 < G_2 < G_3$.

We can easily prove that $G_1 \triangleleft G_3 \implies G_1 \triangleleft G_2$.

I think the following two statements are both false :

- $G_1 \triangleleft G_2 \implies G_1 \triangleleft G_3$,
- $G_2 \triangleleft G_3 \implies G_1 \triangleleft G_3$.

Is there a counter example for each statement?

**Edit.**

In the first case, the counter example is
$G_1 = G_2 = \{ id, (12) \}$, $G_3 = S_3$.

Comment: The use of $\lt$ usually suggests *proper* inclusion, though...

Comment: For 2 consider $A_3\lt S_3\lt S_4$. For an example with $G_2$ normal in $G_3$, the smallest counterexample occurs in a group of order 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both statements, we can take $G_3 = A_4$, $G_2 = \{(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ and $G_1 = \{(1),(12)(34)\}$.

Comment: Is there a method that shows $G_2$ is a normal subgroup of $G_3$ better than just calculating all cases?

Comment: @with-forest: Conjugation in $S_n$ preserves disjoint cycle structure; $G_2$ contains all elements that are products of two disjoint transpositions.